# Any UNIX system that allow to move a file to a directory, rename file in the directory with +rw -x permission?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, history

I'm trying to better understand how UNIX/LINUX file system works.

[file system-on-linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/465350/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-inodes-on-linux/)

> Compared to an inode, a directory structure contains a limited amount
> of information about a file. It only holds the file’s inode number,
> name, and the length of the name.

```
info '(coreutils) File permissions'
```

> 1. permission to read the file.  For directories, this means
>    permission to list the contents of the directory.
> 2. permission to write to (change) the file.  For directories, this
>    means permission to create and remove files in the directory.
> 3. permission to execute the file (run it as a program).  For
>    directories, this means permission to access files in the
>    directory.

Now `read` and `write` permissions mean read and write directory, that is why with no `x` `ls` gives only names. `x` gives `access files` so one can read inode: file permissions, etc. and data - so a file can be accessed provided name is known beforehand.

But why the system (Linux Mint 20 to be exact though as far as I recalled now many UNIX behave same way - but not all operating systems):

```
ls -lad 1
drw-rw-rw- 2 alex alex 60 Oct  5 10:55 1
mv ./test ./1
mv: cannot stat './1/test': Permission denied
mv 1/2 1/3
mv: failed to access '1/3': Permission denied
```

`mv` a file to folder with `+rw -x` produced `permission denied`?  - I have write to directory, the system could have written hardlink to file along with name to the directory and `r` allow to check if file with that name already exists (renaming a file with `mv` produced similar result). Use case would be you can drop the file to directory but not be able to access/change it later. Any reason it does not work that way? Any UNIX systems that allow that?

**Added:**

Based on comment:
`man 'rename(2)'`

> ERRORS EACCES Write  permission  is  denied for the directory containing oldpath or newpath, or, search permission is denied for one of the directories in the path prefix of oldpath or newpath, or oldpath is a directory and does not allow write permission (needed to update the ..  entry).  (See also path_resolution(7).)

So the question becomes: why rename system call need search permission for last part of prefix of newpath? I understand it is easier to check for existence and allowance of replacement that way, but IMO it could have been written in case of no search permission but read permission to check existence by name.

Comment: _"can drop the file to directory but not be able to access/change it later"_ -- well, the `mv` there already tries to access files in the directory, `mv ./test ./1` calls `rename("./test", "./1/test")` etc. Of course you could build a permission system where the `x` bit was not needed, and just the `r` and `w` bits would be enough, but that's not how the one we have works. But of course you're asking _why_ it's like this, and questions like that may be hard to find answers to.

Comment: @ilkkachu, `x` is needed to search for hardlink by name but not give ability to list all contents. I've already explained in detail why I think allowing `mv` with only `rw`  would not be against man pages; and the above use case too.

Comment: I know how it works. I'm merely stating, that the renames you're trying already require access to files in the directory, mentioned in point 3 of your quote.

Comment: @ilkkachu, why `rename` need to find hardlinks and metadata of file to rename to? Only if file with same name exists in the directory to check rights to overwrite; if no such file, then why check it?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here. Under the answer, you argued that "mv does not need search", but that's obviously untrue as you've noticed. If you're arguing the current behaviour is wrong, well, sure, that's a valid viewpoint, but behaviour rooted in over the decades isn't going to change just through one SE question. Then again, if you're asking _why_ it works like that, that's a valid question too, but different from arguing about how it's wrong, and you might want to make it clear you're asking about historical rationale in particular.

Comment: @ilkkachu, I'm arguing current behavior is not as described in man pages (with IMO reasonable understanding of its terms used combined with knowledge of internal file structure).

Comment: @Martian2020, like I said, `mv ./test ./dir` implies `rename("./test", "./dir/test")`, i.e. accessing a filename within the directory `dir`, and as the third point in the quoted text says, you need the `x` permission to access files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

In order to move a file into a directory you need to be able to enumerate the directory contents which is the X permission.

From Wikipedia: *The execute permission grants the ability to execute a file. When set for a directory, the execute permission is interpreted as the search permission: it grants the ability to access file contents and meta-information if its name is known, but not list files inside the directory, unless read is set also.*

More on it here: https://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20030424.html

From `man renameat2` (the syscall `mv` uses):

```
       EACCES Write permission is denied for the directory containing
              oldpath or newpath, or, search permission is denied for
              one of the directories in the path prefix of oldpath or
              newpath, or oldpath is a directory and does not allow
              write permission (needed to update the ..  entry).  (See
              also path_resolution(7).)
```

The execute permission is at least required under Linux and since Linux largely conforms to POSIX I believe all other Unixes work the same way.

I'd say it's a little bit counter-intuitive but it is what it is.

> Any UNIX system that allow to move a file to a directory, rename file in the directory with +rw -x permission?

I'm not aware of such Unixes but then I've worked only with MacOS, Linux, FreeBSD.

Comment: Thanx for the effort, but I've already explained that `mv` does not need search, only check that name does not exist in the directory to check for overwrite - code can do that with read permission. Surely if name does exist, directory permissions do not allow to check for file permissions and overwrite  and overwrite only IMO should give "denied".

Comment: I've messed up something, it's `renameat2(AT_FDCWD, "file", AT_FDCWD, "test/file", RENAME_NOREPLACE) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)` which fails.